# Pkg.precompile error when adding packages in project virtual environment(Julia)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, julia-plots

Pkg.precompile error when adding packages in project virtual environment(Julia)

I experience difficulities adding packages into a project virtual environment.I see these error messages within REPL:[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBLuk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjOu4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u1Gq.png)
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Julia 1.8.I have delete the folder:C:\Users\name.julia\environments\v1.8\Manifest.toml`,but this issus persists.I am using Windows 10.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, None of the images you've linked to show a precompile error. There's version restrictions for compatibility, but that should be fine in general. If there's an actual package precompilation error, please post that part of the error. And it's better to copy-paste the error messages (in full) rather than link to a set of images containing them.